# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have recently shifted to Ubuntu 18.04.2 from Windows 10(64-bit) on my HP 15-DA0330TU Notebook. Since then I cannot connect to Wireless network whereas the Wired connection works fine. Every time I try connecting to Wi-Fi, it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found."
Wi-Fi worked fine while using Windows 10.

Please help me fix this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723

~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de

~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT:
I've ran into the same problem again, though my secure boot is disabled. Please help!

Comment: Summoning Pilot6 or chili555.....

Comment: Show us the output of `lspci` and add it as an edit to your post here - it will help to see if the system detects the card, and will give us an idea of what card you *actually* have in your system.  From there it should be easier to diagnose it.

Comment: Yes, I'm here! Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have edited the answer with the output of the following commands. Please have a look!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723de && dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: Edited. Please have a look!

Comment: Please try disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI.

Comment: Thanks a lot chili555, this worked. I have been trying to fix this since a month. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have again ran into the same problem. My Secure Boot is still disabled but I cannot connect to Wi-Fi yet. Please help!